# Can't connect with SSH to Ubuntu server (20.04) on raspberry pi 4

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, ssh

I need some help regarding my private Ubuntu server. I recently bought a Raspberry Pi 4B. I decided that it was best to turn it into a server with the latest version of Ubuntu server.

I haven't attached a keyboard, mouse or monitor to the Pi as i was planning to only get access to the server with SSH. Now, I can SSH into my Pi when I'm on the same network, but for some reason I don't get access when I'm on a different network. Every time i try to connect from a different network it get the `Connection timed out` error. If I ping the IP address I get really fast response time, that's why this doesn't make sense to me

I checked the status of SSH with `~$ systemctl status ssh` and it does say that SSH is active and running.

I found my IP address with `~$ curl ipv4.icanhazip.com`. I checked the online devices in the dashboard of my router and it does say that it's connected.

`OpenSSH server` is installed and running.
I checked and the `firewall is not active`.

I hope someone can help me out.

Kind regards,

Sleek

Comment: Do you have a router? Are your SSH ports forwarded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By logging in successfully on your LAN, you have conclusively demonstrated that your Pi+Ubuntu server is configured properly.

All of the devices on your network share a single public IP address -- the router's IP address.

When you try to ssh into your network from outside, those packets reach the router first. Set up *port forwarding* on your router, so the router knows that the ssh connections should be sent (forwarded) to the Pi.

It's a router setting that has nothing to do with the Pi or with Ubuntu, nor with the Ubunbtu Server's firewall.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, It works now!